# Why doesn't my function work on page load?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a function as soon as the user lands on the page. I have the following head section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        function sayOK() {
            alert('ok');
        }
        window.onload = sayOK;
   </script>

</head>
```

Why doesn't sayOK() run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code ran fine in testing. You can try moving your script to the footer, just before your closing body tag.

jQuery offers a good onload mechanism, and if you want cross-browser reliability, that would be where I start. Don't reinvent the wheel.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Why the down-vote? He's already loading jQuery in his sample so there's no reason not to use it. Creating custom functions to handle onload is superfluous when he already has access to one and makes maintenance harder down the road.

Comment: This worked. I moved the script right before the closing of body.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped - often times the simplest answer is the best :)

Comment: @illmortem I think there's a good case to be made for trying to make the webdev community move away from jQuery, and teach people best practices in vanilla JS. I downvoted this in an attempt to make it less visible than my answer, that provides a straight vanilla JavaScript solution. Please don't take it personally.

Comment: @korona Thank you for the clarification. Regarding vanilla JavaScript the solution of moving the call to the bottom of the page to ensure page load should satisfy this (i.e. the API already provides an onload event).

Regarding jQuery, I'd be very interested in reading some case examples of why it should be moved away from, if you have any examples in mind. - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a portable way of running your code as soon as the page is loaded:

```
function documentReady (cb) {
  if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    cb();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cb);
  }
}

documentReady(function () {
  // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It works. Try try to create a separate file, for example ok.html, and open it in any browser. It should show the message.